# Can I combine water turbine without power loss?

Tags: generator, water

I have this small 12V water turbine generator.

[image]

I connected one of these in a pipe running from a container on my roof to the ground. (height ~6m) and reached ~9V.

If I buy 6 and put them one after the other along the same pipe, will I have exactly the same amount of energy (force/pressure) but multiplied by 6 ?

I don't think it will slow down the flow of water, or does it ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a fluid mechanics question, not electrical engineering.

Comment: `I don't think it will slow down the flow of water, or does it ?` ... why are you asking this? ... you have one of the turbines ... do an experiment to determine the answer

Comment: A simple way to approach this sort of problems is to think in extremes: If there is no pressure loss you can connect a million in series and supply power to the whole town from your container....

Comment: @Oldfart I agree ! but I can't imagine the flow stopping. So it'll be lower for each turbine, 9V + 8V + 7V + 6V and so on. Or would it be more 9V + 3V + 0V ? That's what I'm wondering.

Comment: No. If you connect them all in series, the flow must be the same through each turbine. Where else could the water possibly go?

Comment: If you only talk about flow and voltage, then you're leaving out half the picture. You don't know how much mechanical power is going in to the thing unless you know the flow rate _and_ the pressure drop.  You don't know how much electrical power is coming out unless you know the voltage _and_ the current. With simple electrical machines, the rotation rate (flow rate in your turbine) and the voltage will be approximately proportional, while the torque (pressure drop) will be approximately proportional to the electric current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're using a turbine generator to convert kinetic energy (water flow) to electrical (the 9V that you're seeing). This will cause a pressure drop, even if you just have one in line with your flow. If you have 6 of them, each will cause a pressure drop, and likely, each will produce a little less power than the one above. it.

how much that pressure drop is will depend on your generator. Each turbine might output roughly the same amount of power and it might seem like the pressure is unaffected, but there there will be some pressure drop by each turbine.

Comment: Thanks I see... So just as a curiosity and about your opinion. if 1 turbine can generate 9V and I installed one just below, how much voltage do you think can be reached ? I need 12V to be reached. :P Can I have at least in theory 9+3 ?

Comment: @bobdylan In order to get higher voltage, you'll need the turbine to spin faster (higher flow rate). Probably the only way to achieve that is with a greater head of water. On the other hand you could use a boost-mode switching power supply to create a regulated 12V supply out from a range of lower input voltages.

Comment: @bobdylan Mattman's answer says, that if you put two in series, you'll get only half as much power from each. OK, but the only requirement you've given so far is voltage. If you put two turbines in series *AND* you connect their electrical outputs together in series, *AND* you don't try to draw too much current from it, then you could (in theory) get twice the voltage.

Answer (score 1):

A turbine generator will produce electricity based on how fast the turbines spin, which is related to the water *flow*. If you put several in series, the flow will be the same in each, therefore the output from each will be about the same.

The flow rate will always adjust itself until the losses match the pressure difference between the ends of the pipe. The bottom is zero. The top is 6 meters of *head*, which equates to about 8 psi. This is only 10-20% of household water pressure, so don't expect a high flow rate from this setup. Therefore, you won't get much power out.

Most of the loss is going to be in the generator, so putting 2 in series will approximately halve the flow rate. Therefore each will produce about half as much power.

You haven't said anything about the load. Based on the low predicted flow rate, you can't  get much current out of this setup. Put a 100 ohm load and see how many volts you get.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer and your willingness to help and teach. I'll try to understand more about it based on your guidelines here. To tell the whole story I have a small solar setup and when my battery is full the energy from the sun is wasted. I thought maybe i could use this moment to activate a pump to fill up a tank 6m high and use it as potential energy later on. Just DIY for learning, probably won't be efficient. But curious what I should do to make it works. So I don't really mind if the Current is low (battery), I will just try to make it work first.

Comment: and my battery is 12v ofc

Comment: I found the generator on Amazon, it is rated at 10 W output. This would probably be with household water pressure of about 70 psi (0.5 MPa). You will likely only get about 10%, or 1W, since your pressure is much lower.

Comment: I would put the water flow in parallel, not series, assuming that you have enough water volume to do this. Then, put the electrical side in series. With no load you may get 18V, but it will quickly drop with a load. Put a diode in series so the generator can't drain the battery.